# Update Function and nWidart Module

Tags: laravel, module

nwidart module for Laravel... without this module it work fine.. but i cant use a "update function" with nwidart/modules..

my routes:

```
Route::put('customer-update/{id}', [CustomerController::class, 'update'])->name('customer-update');

Route::resource('customer',CustomerController::class);
```

My View:

```
<form  action="{{ route('customer.update', $customer->id) }}" method="POST" id="account-edit" name="account-edit">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
....
</form>
```

Error:

Target class [Modules\Customer\Http\Controllers\Modules\Customer\Http\Controllers\CustomerController] does not exist.

i have this problem with all my updates functions, it work without modules

Comment: The error seems to be a namespace one, can you share your CustomerController.php and Modules.php ? the one @Modules\Customer\Http\Controllers\Modules

Comment: Basicly, in `Modules\Customer\Http\Controllers\Modules.php` you used the class`Customer\Http\Controllers\CustomerController` without the leading `\ ` or the `use`.

Comment: with and without \ no work

Comment: where is the error happenong ? which file is reported in the error backstack ? if you dont add more details to your question, we can't help you.

Comment: Only fail with try to update... create work well... 
  luminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class [Modules\Customer\Http\Controllers\Modules\Customer\Http\Controllers\CustomerController] does not exist. The controller exist, and it work without modules

Comment: do you understand that it is a namespace issue ? check where you used the class `CustomerController::class` (in the config of the modules, in any declaration) and fix the namespace.

Comment: Hi!!! it's a issue with a module package! i make it work and i report the bug! Thanks you!

Comment: So, to make it work you had to comment out the module namespace ? like shown in this issue report  https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/issues/1245

Comment: Yes!! now i making PT to solve it :) Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the namespace in the route file for all controllers

For Example:

```
use Modules\Customer\Http\Controllers\CustomerController;
```

Comment: i try this... with \Modules\Customer and with Modules\Customer (note the first \)